# Updated state not useful in the return statement of a method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button inside my render function, onClick of which a method is called which displays a popup with a simple form with a input text box and a button. The thing is I want this button to be disabled if the input text box is empty.

I tried setting a variable 'name' in state and use it. Even thought the state value is updating when the user makes some changes in the input text box, but I'm not able to use this updated value for enabling or disabling the button.

```
render(){
  return(
    <button type='button' onClick={this.createUser} />
  );
}

private createUser = (e) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={event => this.setState({name : event.target.value})}></input>
      <button disabled={!this.state.name}>Create</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `onChange` value should be a function

Comment: also you're missing closing curly bracket in `onChange` value

Comment: Yeah, I have that in code, just missed it while adding here. Updated now

Comment: how do you create the pop-up? Using portals?

Comment: It's a custom component created using --- const Modal = createFactory(ReactBootstrap.Modal);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this.

```js
class Application extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    show: false,
  };
  handlePopup = (show) => {
    this.setState({show});
  }
  handleChangeText = (e) => {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value});
  }
  renderPopup = (value, isVisible) => {
    if(isVisible)
      return (
        <div>
            <input value={value} onChange={this.handleChangeText} />
            <button disabled={!value} onClick={(e) => this.handlePopup(false)} >Create</button>
        </div>
      );
  }
  
  render(){
    const { show, name } = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <button type='button' onClick={(e) => this.handlePopup(true)}>Click here</button>
        {this.renderPopup(name, show)}
        <div>{name}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/react.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I know this would work but I there's a lot of logic involved in between and I cant add all that in the main return inline. I just posted a dummy sample of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind this to the event handler, when it updates the state, it isn't updating your local state:

```
render(){
  return(
    <button type='button' onClick={this.createUser.bind(this)} />
  );
}

private createUser = (e) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={this.setState({name : event.target.value})></input>
      <button disabled={this.state.name.length == 0}>Create</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note for the onclick of the button, I binded this which allows your local state to be updated.

Comment: Tried this, but still not working. Actually in real code, I have one more method in between onClick of button and createUser(). And from that method call goes to createUser()

Comment: Try binding the method in between as well. For me usually, it's always the binding that causes an issue.

Comment: tried that but now getting: react.development.js?820d:88 Uncaught Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try my approach?

```
render(){
  return(
    <button type='button' onClick={this.createUser(!this.state.name)} />
  );
}

private createUser = (disabled) => (e) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={event => this.setState({name : event.target.value})}></input>
      <button disabled={disabled}>Create</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If this.state.name get updated in main render function according to input's changes, this value would be delivered as a parameter on createUser.